# FHIR Resource Schema/Spec

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

How to get one single FHIR Schema for a Resource with all the parent and child attributes in the schema. When I looked into the FHIR Schema, it has lot of child Schemas inside each resource Schema, The Schema is defined at a entity level and not at a Resource level, A Resource is made of multiple child Schemas.

For Ex :
For Patient Resource, We have Patient.Schema under Patient.Schema we have HumanName.Schema.

Is there a Tool or Utility, that is available readily to build a JSON Specification at a Resource level from this multiple Parent and Child schema for a Resource ?

Or can we get a Resource JSON with all the available attributes (both parent and child attributes), So that we can build our own json schema from it ?

Comment: This was already raised and answered here: http://community.fhir.org/t/fhir-resource-schema-spec-creation

Per FHIR's [Rules for asking questions](https://confluence.hl7.org/display/FHIR/FHIR+Rules+for+Asking+Questions), please don't ask the same question in multiple places simultaneously.